# updating FIREBASE over PHP fails

Tags: php, firebase, updating, failover

I have a problem, I tried updating JSON formated data with CURL to my online database: Firebase. It works fine at first, but when I send Data witch I have sent somewhen before it doesn´t get stored. I am sending a combination of a few GET-Variables.

```
if($_GET['user']!='')
{
$user_url = str_replace('.' , ',' , $_GET['user']);
$url='https://websitenew.firebaseio.com/' . $user_url . '.json';
$data = array('author'=>$_GET['user'], 'temp'=>$_GET['temp'], 'druck'=>$_GET['press'], 'notMoving'=>$_GET['move'], 'gpsx'=>$_GET['gpsx'], 'gpsy'=>$_GET['gpsy']);
$data_json = json_encode($data);
$header = array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_json));

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PATCH");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_json);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should Ideally work with get Variable.  If that does not work then try mapping it to a variable in php and then creating a JSON out of it.  If the API does not work.  Please try out the below one which I had used in my project and it is fully functioning too.

> https://github.com/eldhosemjoy/firebase

I hope this git could help you understand the operations with firebase too.